# No access to Linux shell in an mrsdeploy remote session

Tags: r, microsoft-r, deployr

I've logged into a Microsoft R Server using `mrsdeploy::remoteLogin()`

Next I start a remote session with `mrsdeploy::remoteCommandLine()`

If I try to use `system("pwd")` I get no response.

I'm guessing access to the shell is blocked - does anyone know where this is controlled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the answer to this.

The remote session does have access to the shell.  You need to use `intern = TRUE` to see the result.

For example `system("pwd", intern = TRUE)`

Comment: You can also use `system2` which should handle issues like this more gracefully.